# Solr Custom Request Handler: creating queries with group clauses?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm writing my own request handler. 
After I get the user input from "q"

```
String q = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
```

I want to build a complex query using group clauses:

example:

```
foo&group.truncate=true&group.ngroups=true&group.field=id&group.sort=date desc&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

I'm seeing examples on line where they are doing following:

Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term(q));

So in this case the q, would be the query string I create?

and after we create the query how do we actually perform the search?

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone deep with these links but check to see if it provides any clue to your Q.

- [Solr Search RequestHandler](http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/solr-search-request-handlers.html)
- [Solr Custom RequestHandler - injecting query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182183/solr-custom-requesthandler-injecting-query-parameters)
- [Solr: a custom Search RequestHandler](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html)
- [Custom SOLR Search Components - 2 Dev Tricks](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/04/custom-solr-search-components-2-dev.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still does not answer my question. I'm looking for examples on how to build a complex query from user entered input, ex: user enters "foo" and I have to add group-clauses.

Comment: @user1998719 My pleasure! But please be more clear with your question and try to include some additional information for supporting your Q. like,
 * Which Solr version you are using?
 * How you are using it? like using SolrJ or any other.
 * The title of the question must reflect the exact clue of your Q.
 * Any supported links that you have referred.
 * screen shots of your attempts. e.t.c. 

With this it is likely draw more attention of the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't have experience in writing RequestHandler and I Don't know how difficult it is.

If your requirement is to add more filters to the existing the query, I think it is easy to write a SearchComponent.

You can write a CustomComponent extending SearchComponent. In that Custom component, you can override the prepare method as below:

```
public void prepare(ResponseBuilder responseBuilder) throws IOException {
 BooleanFilter booleanFilter = new BooleanFilter();
 TermsFilter termFilter = new TermsFilter(new Term("name", value));
 booleanFilter.add(new FilterClause(termFilter, Occur.MUST));
 /*
   Create a filtered Query with the with the filter created and the actual query
  */
 FilteredQuery query = new FilteredQuery(responseBuilder.getQuery(),booleanFilter);
 // Set the new query into the response builder.
 responseBuilder.setQuery(query);
}
```

Once you have search component ready, you can create the searchComponent in solrConfig.xml
as below:

```
 <searchComponent name="customComponent" class="com.CustomComponent">
<lst name="parameterName">
    <str name="key">value</str>
</lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Then You can add this as a last component in the existing Request Handler

```
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>customComponent</str>
   <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think your solution is more related to how to build a custom filter.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your use case is to modify the query to more complex query, Not the way request handler work right? If that is the case, a custom component itself will solve your problem. You don't need to write custom request handler.

Comment: AGAIN I need to know how to build queries with group by clauses in a custom request handler. Please don't answer any questions if you don't have the answer.